# Risks of storing Open GL-ES shader code in plain text

Tags: java, opengl-es

I'm creating a video app that applies certain filters to the video using GLES20 on Android. All the examples I have seen hard code their shader source code as strings, i.e.:

```
private final String fragmentShaderCode =
    "precision mediump float;" +
    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
    "void main() {" +
    "gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
    "}";
```

However, it becomes cumbersome to edit complex shaders with all the commas and line breaks. I thought of writing my shaders as a raw text file resource so I could make use of indentation etc. and write a function to load the shaders from the text file into a String before compiling at run time. What are the key things to consider or risks in doing it this way?

I'm assuming intellectual property is the main risk, but assuming keeping the source code secret isn't a big deal, any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about IP, text in a text file isn't any more or less secure than text in a binary file, it's still trivially discoverable. Given you have to handle text somewhere, at best you can obfuscate, but on the whole you don't really have a choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Per the question, I'm not really concerned about IP, more about any injection risks.

Comment: Why is the risk of modifying a shader any different to modifying any other part of the application binary or data set? A "normal user" can't. A "power user" with a rooted device can break the app, but that's nothing new or specific to shaders.

Comment: I would think one requires recompiling (i.e. modifying hard code, presumably unsigned), where as the other could be executed by my signed application. Given the lack of responses, and the point you raised, I'm going to say I'm probably being paranoid. In the end, Android controls what my app can access/do anyway, anyone willing to root their device to do this is doing so at their own risk. Thanks for the response. I wonder why none of the examples online do it this way, as it seems much easier to edit the shader.